# MIssing ) after argument list for jQuery in WordPress

Tags: jquery, syntax

I'm still learning the ropes and I'm getting this error in the console.

You can find a link to the test page `[here][1]`

```
missing ) after argument list
```

For this jQuery code:

```
    jQuery.noConflict();
 (function ($) {
     function readyFn() {
     $.fn.extend({
         Segment: function ( ) {
       $(this).each(function (){
         var self = $(this);
         var onchange = self.attr('onchange');
         var wrapper = $("<div>",{class: "ui-segment"});
         $(this).find("option").each(function (){
           var option = $("<span>",{class: 'option',onclick:onchange,text: $(this).text(),value: $(this).val()});
           if ($(this).is(":selected")){
             option.addClass("active");
           }
           wrapper.append(option);
         });
         wrapper.find("span.option").click(function (){
           wrapper.find("span.option").removeClass("active");
           $(this).addClass("active");
           self.val($(this).attr('value'));
         });
         $(this).after(wrapper);
         $(this).hide();
       });
         }
     });

 $(".segment-select").Segment();

 var options = {
   monthly: [
         {price: 25, link: 'link1'},
             {price: 45, link: 'link2'},
                 {price: 145, link: 'link3'},
     ],
     yearly: [
         {price: 300, link: 'link4'},
             {price: 540, link: 'link5'},
                 {price: 640, link: 'link6'},
     ]
 }

 function fillContent(interval) {
     var data = options[interval];

   $('.content').each(function(index) {
       var content = $(this);

         content.find('span.price').text('$' + data[index]span.price);
         content.find('span.interval').text(interval);
         content.find('span.link').attr('href', data[index]span.link);

     });
 }

 // initialization

 fillContent("monthly");

 $('.ui-segment').on("click", '.option', function() {
   var interval = $(this).attr('value');

     fillContent(interval);
 });
     }

     $(document).ready(readyFn);
 })(jQuery);
```

What would be the issue? I do see this error in the console pointing to the `content.find('span.price').text('$' + data[index]span.price);` part of the code.

[Image: Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2wL8.png)

Comment: What is `span` supposed to be in `data[index]span.price`? Shouldn't it be just `data[index].price`?

Comment: Well, you might say. I changed it back to `.price` but that didn't work. Also when I inspect the element it says `span.price`. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: The DOM element doesn't have anything to do with the object you're trying to access.

Comment: Understood. Well, tried different variations of price. Also loading scripts in footer didn't work. 

Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

For what I see here, your jquery.noConflict(); it's not closed in the right way, try to following the code below:

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
 (function ($) {
     function readyFn() {
     $.fn.extend({
         Segment: function ( ) {
       $(this).each(function (){
         var self = $(this);
         var onchange = self.attr('onchange');
         var wrapper = $("<div>",{class: "ui-segment"});
         $(this).find("option").each(function (){
           var option = $("<span>",{class: 'option',onclick:onchange,text: $(this).text(),value: $(this).val()});
           if ($(this).is(":selected")){
             option.addClass("active");
           }
           wrapper.append(option);
         });
         wrapper.find("span.option").click(function (){
           wrapper.find("span.option").removeClass("active");
           $(this).addClass("active");
           self.val($(this).attr('value'));
         });
         $(this).after(wrapper);
         $(this).hide();
       });
         }
     });
     }
 });

 $(".segment-select").Segment();

 var options = {
   monthly: [
         {price: 25, link: 'link1'},
             {price: 45, link: 'link2'},
                 {price: 145, link: 'link3'},
     ],
     yearly: [
         {price: 300, link: 'link4'},
             {price: 540, link: 'link5'},
                 {price: 640, link: 'link6'},
     ]
 }

 function fillContent(interval) {
     var data = options[interval];

   $('.content').each(function(index) {
       var content = $(this);

         content.find('span.price').text('$' + data[index]span.price);
         content.find('span.interval').text(interval);
         content.find('span.link').attr('href', data[index]span.link);

     });
 }

 // initialization

 fillContent("monthly");

 $('.ui-segment').on("click", '.option', function() {
   var interval = $(this).attr('value');

     fillContent(interval);
 });

     $(document).ready(readyFn);
```

Comment: Thanks. However that didn't work `Unexpected end of input`.